# SQL server over the internet

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've recently migrated the back end of a Microsoft Access database to an SQL server. My hope is, that I can distribute my MS Access programs as the front end, which connect over the internet to a specific SQL server for each client.

I'd also like to be able to use SQL Server Management studio to manage an SQL server over the internet.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You can't do that... SQL Server management studio is for Microsoft SQL Server, and Access is another database, just like you can't connect to postgre in SQL Management studio..

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you want to connect to database through internet, just set the connection string to that server's IP..

Comment: When you have a Static Valid IP address you can connect to your server by using it ;).

Comment: you can use a domain name (dynamic ip is possible) to allow your customer to connect to your sql server. and you also need license($$) to do that . Usually it's expensive and most people just use free db server like mysql to do the job. Connecting to mysql with ms access might be a little harder but it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect MS Access to a remote SQL Server using the generalized DSN-less call of the [Driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/):

`DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=<ServerAddress>;Database=<DBname>;UID=<UserID>;PWD=<Password>;`

OR

`DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=<ServerAddress>;Database=<DBname>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

Simply, change `<ServerAddress>` to database server's IP Address or location address. If you need to create linked tables, you will need to establish connection in VBA, then link using `TableDefs`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the remote SQL server is configured to accept connections coming from outside .

So in your Management studio you try this way

[image]

Replace the ip address with the server address and enter your login and password. I am assuming that the remote instance name is MSSQLSERVER .